# App loading splash screen with processbar and Text for showing percentage of loading

Tags: android, layout, splash-screen

I am working on splash screen for my android app. The screen starts from my MainActivity.java, in which onCreate() method contains the following code. Also the same activity class is loading maps in its onResume() method and in it i m loading a new layout which is activity_main.xml. That xml has black screen and no background screen.

> MainActivity.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (progressStatus < 100) {
                    progressStatus += 1;

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                            textView.setText(progressStatus + "/"
                                    + progressBar.getMax());
                        }
                    });
                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

        compass = new CompassSensor(this, compassHandler);
    }
```

my layout for loading_screen.xml is as follow.

> loading_screen.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_screen_loading" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The problem i m facing is that only black screen shows during app loading. I tried to debug the problem but all my efforts were useless. Plz help.

Comment: How about to use Looper.getMainLooper() to do status change in UI thread?Also, how do you load map from onResume()? I think AsyncTask could be used to load map data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not attempt this in `onCreate`, if you expect visual changes. Nothing is shown to user during `onCreate`. I am aware of `Thread.sleep(200)`.

You may want to try doing it in your `onResume`, just **after** calling `super.onResume`. The way you described it, `R.layout.loading_screen` is not even supposed to be shown.

Also, if you're using `AsyncTask` to load maps, Developers lets you know how to publish progress. Take a look at this: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Maybe you could add this prior work (with progress on `R.layout.loading_screen`) to asynchronous task, too.

Comment: Ok thanks @Nikola Tulimirovic, I m able to run the splash screen but now the problem is that there is a map loading process which must be initiated in onResume. As i have .sqldb files in specific folder. Now if i put whole this code before super.resume() the splash screen runs perfect but after Hunder percent loading my code doesnt run and it seems logical. I cant skip me code but what i m asking is that while Application is under loading process why not splash screen works in oncreate method of MainActivity.java? 

'code'

Comment: @SaifHaider: Have you considered adding one introductory activity (main, launcher), which starts your MainAcitivity? I know this may seem lame, but it may turn out cleaner (no layout choices for MainActivity). Don't forget to edit manifest so that IntroActivity looks as MainActivity looks now, regarding intent-filter.

Comment: You r right. I will by the way thanks for ur advice.